# How to get MDC logging working for Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch, mdc

In Spring Batch it would be great to keep track of the execution thread through logging. However, MDC does not seem to work.

`MDC.put("process", "batchJob");`
`logger.info("{}; status={}", getJobName(), batchStatus.name());`

Anyone got MDC working in Spring Batch?

Comment: I suppose you have to redefine log config file for SB packages adding extra information (MDC key, thread name and other info) to `pattern` property

Comment: of course, that is done.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding a `JobExecutionListener` like that:

```
public class Slf4jBatchJobListener implements JobExecutionListener {

    private static final String DEFAULT_MDC_UUID_TOKEN_KEY = "Slf4jMDCFilter.UUID";
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase();
        MDC.put(DEFAULT_MDC_UUID_TOKEN_KEY, token);
        logger.info("Job {} with id {} starting...", jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName(), jobExecution.getId());
    }

    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        logger.info("Job {} with id {} ended.", jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName(), jobExecution.getId());
        MDC.remove(DEFAULT_MDC_UUID_TOKEN_KEY);
    }
}
```

Because some jobs are multi-threaded, I had to add also a TaskDecorator in order to copy the DMC from the parent thread to the subthread like this:

```
public class Slf4JTaskDecorator implements TaskDecorator {

    @Override
    public Runnable decorate(Runnable runnable) {
        Map<String, String> contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
        return () -> {
            try {
                MDC.setContextMap(contextMap);
                runnable.run();
            } finally {
                MDC.clear();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Set the TaskDecorator to the TaskExecutor:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
    taskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(maxThreads);
    taskExecutor.setTaskDecorator(new Slf4JTaskDecorator());
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

And lastly, update the logging pattern in properties:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    level: "%5p %X{Slf4jMDCFilter.UUID}"
```