# Spring Batch MDC Logging

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, logback, mdc

I'm wanting to know how to log things such as the `Job Name` and `Execution ID` using MCD in Spring Batch.

Here's some code:

**bootstrap.properties**

this file has a list of items I currently log, and I've added `execId` as the 3rd element here.

```
logging.pattern.level=%5p [%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{sessionId:-},%X{execId:-},%X{program:-},%X{mainframeId:-}]
spring.application.name=mcc
spring.profiles.active=globals,local,local-override
```

**MCC Application**

this file has my main method. When I manually set the field here with `MDC.put("execId", "12345");` I see it in the log, but I don't understand how to put the actual information I need here.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MccApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MDC.put("execId", "12345");
        SpringApplication.run(MccApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I would appreciate any insight :) Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer** : I am not familiar with spring-batch

`MDC` will work for you to log Job Name and Execution ID along with the log statements because MDC has a thread affinity. So if you put something to MDC while in a thread, then that will be available to you (and to logback) through out the lifecycle of that thread. So if you put `MDC.put("execId", "12345");` in your main method, that will only be available in the main thread.

The Job Name and Execution ID makes sense only in any child thread that the spring batch may spawn (I am running on wild assumptions here, as I am not familiar with spring batch). So add `MDC.put("execId", "12345");` at the beginning point of your actual Job, not in the main() method.

Comment: Thank you for your response and advice, I'll try your suggestions and post back here with my results

Comment: some interesting read here : http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2015/09/using-log-mdc-in-multi-thread-helloworld-example.html

Comment: Thank you for the link and input. I have a much more clear idea of what to do now.

Comment: @Josh Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the MDC in a listener, for example one that you add for each step. During the step's building (with its builder), do `listener(logCompletingStepExecutionListener);` with a (static-defined) listener like:

```java
public class LogCompletingStepExecutionListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    private static final String LOG_MDC_CONTEXT_KEY_STEP_ID = "Step-ID";

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        StepExecutionListener.super.beforeStep(stepExecution);
        MDC.put(LOG_MDC_CONTEXT_KEY_STEP_ID, stepExecution.getStepName() + "_" + stepExecution.getJobExecutionId() + "_" + stepExecution.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        MDC.remove(LOG_MDC_CONTEXT_KEY_STEP_ID);
        return StepExecutionListener.super.afterStep(stepExecution);
    }
}
```

As said by @so-random-dude , it will not comes in other threads. For multi-threaded jobs, see the TaskDecorator in https://stackoverflow.com/a/68347374/7251133 (I didn't test it).