# How do I add a request identifier to a Quartz Job instance's log messages?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, slf4j, quartz, mdc

We use MDC to add a request id to HTTP requests in our Spring Boot application using SLF4J.

We do this by adding a `GenericFilterBean` that intercepts the request, converts to HTTTP, and writes the desired information to `MDC.put(...);`

What is the correct pattern for doing this on, for example, a QuartzJob that uses a CronTrigger to launch jobs? Or a Spring Batch job?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it for **Spring Batch** by adding a `JobExecutionListener`, similar to what you have done for the HTTP with the `GenericFilterBean`.

In `beforeJob()` you can do `MDC.put(...);` and in `afterJob()` you can do `MDC.remove(...);`

Also, I added a `TaskDecorator` to copy the DMC from the parent thread to the sub-threads in case of a multi-threaded Job.

You can find a more detailed answer with code, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68347374/6837191